# how to save api data into a localstorage?

Tags: javascript, api

I'm getting data from an API but i can't save my data into a localStorage.

I've already tried a couple of things but i can't seem to find the problem.

`giveUsers();`

```
function giveUsers() {

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
  })

  .then(function (data) {
    showUsers(data.results);
  })

  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  });

  let showUsers = (users) => {
      users.forEach(user => {
        // console.log(user.registered.age);
        // console.log(user.location.city);
        let firstName = user.name.first;
        let id = user.id;

        console.log(firstName);
        localStorage.setItem('allUsers', firstName);  
     });
  };}
}


if(localStorage.getItem('allUsers')){
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('allUsers'));
}
```

I want my data into the localStorage.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('allUsers', firstName);` does look like only the firstName is saved. You can only save strings in localStorage so you need to convert your users to a string like: `localStorage.setItem('allUsers', JSON.stringify(users))`. And on retrival parse the string again `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allUsers'));`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I understand your question correctly.

you can use `async` and `await` for your fetch. when you fetch data this needs a little time to get a response from a server because of that every time you set something null in your local storage.

you can find information about `async/await` [here](https://javascript.info/async-await).

and about local storage visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_setitem.asp)

Answer (score 3):

You need to store your data as a string in localStorage

so use JSON.stringify();

```
let showUsers = (users) => {
  users.forEach(user => {       

    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));  

  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code it looks like you are setting localstorage for each user, effectively overwriting the last user added due to the same "key value"
You should put them in a list and store your array as JSON. Remeber to use "window.localstorage": 
It should look something like this

```
window.localStorage.setItem('allusers', JSON.stringify(listOfUsers));
```